# get xml-field with property

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

this is my xml-file:

```
 <artist>
     <name>Have Heart</name>
     <playcount>2588</playcount>
     <tagcount>0</tagcount>
     <mbid>e519e012-e1a3-4592-b3f6-5a16227ab654</mbid>
     <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Have+Heart</url>
     <streamable>1</streamable>
     <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/29086375.jpg</image>
     <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/29086375.jpg</image>
     <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/29086375.jpg</image>
     <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/29086375.jpg</image>
     <image size="mega">
          http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/29086375/Have+Heart.jpg
     </image>
</artist>
```

I'm looping through the data like this:

```
for each(artistXML in artistList.artists)
{
    var artistName:String = artistXML.artist.name;
    var artistPic:String = 
    insertArtistUrl = "http://localhost:8888/flexapp/insert_artist.php?";   
}
```

How can I get one of the image tags? Let's say the large one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
artistXML.artist.image.(@size=="large")
```